# TypeLoadException in Xamarin.Forms project without TypeName

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-cognitive-services

I'm working on a simple ProjectOxford Face and Emotion APIs demo with Xamarin.Forms

I added the Face and Emotion APIs from Nuget to the PCL Forms project and all platform-specific projects I get a TypeLoadException but the TypeName property is empty, so I don't know what's not loading.

The "Link Behavior" setting in the iOS project is "Don't Link" and the app runs in the simulator, selects a picture but when it hits the method that is supposed to send it to Face and Emotion APIs I get the exception below.

```
System.TypeLoadException: Failure has occurred while loading a type.
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine] (TStateMachine& stateMachine) [0x00031] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/9.9.0.719/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:316
  at HelloForms.FaceViewModel.DoAnalyzePhoto () [0x0000f] in <filename unknown>:0
  at HelloForms.FaceViewModel+<FaceViewModel>c__async8.MoveNext () [0x00021] in .../HelloForms/XPlat/HelloForms/ViewModels/FaceViewModel.cs:115
  at --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/9.9.0.719/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>m__0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/9.9.0.719/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1018
  at UIKit.UIKitSynchronizationContext+<Post>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1381/3afb4af5/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIKitSynchronizationContext.cs:24
  at Foundation.NSAsyncActionDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1381/3afb4af5/source/maccore/src/Foundation/NSAction.cs:163
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1381/3afb4af5/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1381/3afb4af5/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
  at HelloForms.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in .../HelloForms/XPlat/iOS/Main.cs:17
```

Comment: Did you try using a device instead of Simulator. Probably the simulator is not able to read the picture.

Comment: The simulator worked fine with a forked version of ProjectOxford SDK built locally, then I noticed they made it PCL and tried their packages for Face and Emotion